# Packing, Memory Alignment and Endianness in Stringstream

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, stringstream

I am using Eclipse to debug a program. I am unsure if Memory Browser view is displaying the memory correctly.

I have 2 structs and a stringstream as:

```
#pragma pack(1)
struct dbHeader
{
    uint8_t    blockID;
    uint32_t   blockLen;
};

struct dbOpen
{
    char       namestr[10];
    uint8_t    blk_version;    
    uint32_t   reserved1;      
    uint16_t   CreatorInfo[4]; 
    uint32_t   LDBVersion;    
    uint16_t   reserved2;      
    uint32_t   ObjectProperty; 
    uint8_t    reserved3[38];  
    uint8_t    creator;        
};
#pragma pack()

dbHeader    dbHdr;
dbOpen      DBOpen;

std::stringstream Buffer(std::iostream::in | std::iostream::out);
```

I am filling in these structs and writing them into the string stream

```
dbHdr.blockID  = 0x12;
dbHdr.blockLen = 0x456789AB;
memset(&DBOpen, 0, sizeof(DBOpen));
strncpy(DBOpen.namestr, "@@DBOPEN", countof(DBOpen.namestr));

Buffer.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&dbHdr), sizeof(dbHdr));
Buffer.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&DBOpen), sizeof(DBOpen));
```

I am sure that packing(1) is working correctly, since `sizeof(dbHdr)` is 5 and `sizeof(dbOpen)` is 72.

Then, I read the stringstream into a regular string as:

```
int size = (int) Buffer.str().size();
char* generated_str = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
Buffer.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(generated_str), size);
```

And, check the memory location of generated_str in the Memory Browser view of Eclipse. Note that I am using Little Endian.

What I see is:

> 0x1189A888  6789AB12 44404045 45504F42 0000004E  .«.gE@@DBOPEN...

I feel it is not correct. Can you help me analyze this output?

Comment: The flakiness of binary operations and C-style code aside, are you calling `Buffer.seekg(0, Buffer.beg)` before reading?

Comment: @user657267 It shouldn't be necessary; a `std::stringstream` maintains separate read and write positions.  (But of course, this is total abuse of `std::stringstream`.  I don't know what he's trying to accomplish, but this is certainly not the right way.)

Comment: How is the memory browser of Eclipse displaying the memory.  Of hand, it looks like it is treating it as 4 byte entities, with the initial value the address.  Since you're not writing four byte entities, the relationship between what it displays and what you write is tenuous at best.  If you look at the first data value, `6789AB12`, the `12` is the first byte you wrote, the `AB` the second, and so on.

Comment: @user657267 I tried both ways, it doesn't affect.

Comment: @JamesKanze yes, 12 is the first byte I write. but I don't understand the placement of 0x456789AB.

Comment: Eclipse is displaying a four byte entity; the first four bytes you wrote, as if it were a little endian 4 byte unsigned.  The first byte you wrote was `12` (the `blockID` field), the second `AB` (the low order byte of the `blockLen` field), and so on.  Eclipse knows nothing of the structures you used in writing the data; it just displays the bytes as if they were `uint32_t[]`.

Comment: You're reading and writing the data on the *same client*. You can cross endian-issues off your list (well, not entirely, you have plenty of them, just not in *this* case). Have you considered putting that stream in `std::ios::binary` mode ? (not that I've ever tried such insanity with a string stream).

Comment: @WhozCraig It's a `stringstream`, there is no binary mode.

Comment: @JamesKanze So the allowance of [`std::ios::binary` according to cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/basic_stringstream) is a mistake? I reviewed the standard and saw no restriction on string streams concerning open mode (or I missed it, which wouldn't be the first time), so if its there, do-tell.

Comment: @WhozCraig Good question.  The standard doesn't specify any behavior for this, so formally, it's undefined behavior.  From a quality of implementation point of view, I would expect an error, but there are arguments for just ignoring the flag.  The document you cite is clearly in error, however; there is no binary mode for a `stringbuf`.

Comment: @JamesKanze I'll certainly defer to you on that, since as I recall you spent a helluva lot of time in the past on the business-end of io stream programming. Its interesting to me that it does (at least on my Mac with clang++) "work", (embedded nullchar's and all, as one would hope), but with no definitive behavior, I certainly wouldn't use it. Relying on *observed*-behavior rather than defined-behavior is rarely a good idea. Thanks for the time.

Comment: @WhozCraig Most of my io stream programming was under Unix, where binary and text modes don't count.  Just out of curiosity, I tried it with VS and g++, under Windows.  In both cases, the option was just ignored.  Which sort of makes sense (although I would have preferred an error): if I insert a `'\n'` into an `std::ostringstream`, I want a `'\n'` in the string I'm building, not a `"\r\n"`.  Even if I don't specify binary mode when constructing the `std::ostringstream`.  I suspect that some of the other flags are irrelevant as well; as it stands, all but `in` and `out` are undefined.